# REST service in salesforce (FORBIDDEN)

Tags: apex, rest-service

I am writing a REST service in apex, and getting the below error message.

```
<Errors>
<Error>
<errorCode>FORBIDDEN</errorCode>
<message>
You do not have access to the Apex class named: JobOrderFeedXML
</message>
</Error>
</Errors>
```

Basically, below is my class structure.

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/myFeedXML/*')
global class myFeedXML 
{
    @HttpGet
    global static void doGet() 
    {
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        RestResponse res = RestContext.response;

        //generate xml
        .....

        res.addHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
        res.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(xmlOutput);
    }
}
```

Anything wrong with the code?
Any input will be so helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the case of a Force.com Site the Apex class must be enabled on the special Guest profile associated with the site.

Setup > Develop > Sites > [your site label] > Public Access Settings > Enabled Apex Classes

Comment: Thanks for the detail info provided. It helps me a lot :D

Answer (score 6):

This is happening because your user (Profile of the User ) does not have access to the apex class.

Under profiles ,please give access to the myFeedXML class and should work.